# Yii2 only show data that has attached time less than current time

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How do I can select data to show based on comparation in yii2 Activerecord? My data record from db contain column `depTime`. So I want to show only data that has `depTime` less than current time.
Here is my function in my controller.

```
public function actionSelectedTeam($id) {
    $searchModel = new TeamSearch();
    $dataProvider= $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination = [
        'pageSize' => 5
    ];

    return $this->render('team-info', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Or there is another way to do that? I mean outside this method, maybe from the model.

Thankyou.

Comment: what is the type of the column `datetime` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the column type is time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have the records displayed that are smaller than the current time, other than they are some kind of reservations and you are providing future date/time manually.

You haven't specified what is the type of the `depTime` column, I assume that you have a `datetime` column, you can use the `time()` and `now()` function to achieve this.

You can add the following line in your search model's `search()` method before you return the `$dataProvider` which is subtracting the `depTime` from the current time and if the result is positive it will include the record.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>', new Expression('time(now()) - time(depTime)'), 0]);
```

Comment: It's work, thankyou. I add the linecode inside the `search()` method, but I change the operator to `<`. What is the `0` standing for? is that for the comparator for result of `time(now()) - time(depTime)`?

Comment: @Blackjack yes it subtracts the `current time -saved time` and if the result is `< 0` then it means the current time is smaller than the saved